# Javascript change margin of picture to input value

Tags: javascript, styles, submit

I want to use javascript to make a function for changing margin of picture based on the value of a number input. but it doesn't work as expected

```js
function changeStyle() {

  x = document.getElementById("num").value;
  document.getElementById("change").style.margin = x + "px";
}
```

```html
<form id="TheForm">
  <input id="num" type="number" onchange="changeStyle();" />
  <br/><input value="Submit" type="button" onclick="changestyle();" /><br/>
  <img id="change" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/">

</form>
```

Comment: It seems working... when I input a number and click submit, the margin is applied. A similar jsfiddle is also made for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/4fupmves/

Comment: I created a snippet. You have a spelling mistake on the button - changestyle instead of changeStyle - the input field works

Comment: Voting to close _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: @arshimen, can you describe what exactly "doesn't work as expected"?